# SQL - Why Use CTEs?

Tags: sql-server

So, I'm an intermediate level SQL developer and recently I've been seeing a ton of discussions surrounding CTEs (Common Table Expressions). Everywhere I look, I see people saying that it's this amazing thing:

> CTEs (Common Table Expressions) are one of the most beautiful and the most powerful feature of SQL Server and are boon to SQL Server developers. These not only simplifies most of the complex operations in T-SQL but also do a lot more than one can imagine.
>
> User Comment from the Microsoft Technet article on using CTEs.

From what I've seen myself and read online, a CTE is essentially just a "self-populating" temp table that can only be used once.  The only benefit I see is that the CTE cleans itself up, unlike the temp table which is bound to the session.  I've also seen a lot of comments about recursion but have never come across a case where I would need to use it; I feel like this is very specific to a certain type of problem?

**In short:** Are CTEs severely circumstantial or am I missing something hugely powerful here?  I've yet to see any real benefit to using a CTE over a temp table.

Comment: Apart from the fact they they can be recursive, isn't it great to reduce complexity in sql? That alone is enough for me to use them regularly. Powerful can mean: 1.more readable 2.more maintainable 3. safer

Comment: As you just said, recursion is one benefit, the fact that you haven't come across a case where you need it doesn't need that it's not a benefit. Another big one for me is readability. You can go to [this link](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14490/common-table-expression-cte-benefits) to read more about them

Comment: That's the problem: I don't see how they reduce complexity.  I understand that you can break apart a query into smaller sections but I can do that with Temp Tables.  Sorry, maybe a better question is: why would I ever use a CTE when I could use a much more flexible (IMO) temp table that lets me manipulate data and continue to use it for the life cycle of the statement/procedure?  As for readability, I'll have to get used to that.  Because I don't use them, I'm not familiar with the syntax which makes readability harder for me - that's 100% just a learning curve though.

Comment: @Lamak - thanks for the link, that cleared up a couple questions that were bouncing around in my head.

Comment: Reduced complexity...you don't have to define the datatypes or even the column names. You don't have to worry about checking if it already exists. You don't have to drop it. Often times if you need to reference a given result set more than once in a procedure that is a good indication that the procedure needs some help to be more set based.

Comment: @TimSchmelter that isn't quite right.If the CTE has more data than fits in memory it will write it to disc just like a table variable.

Comment: It's a broad question, each have their uses, and you should find some clarification here:  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13112/whats-the-difference-between-a-cte-and-a-temp-table

Comment: People consider a CTE to have better readabilty because it's broken apart from a query that uses it.  `SELECT from <cte defined above>` is cleaner to read than `select from table1, (<giant derived table here>) as table2...`.

Comment: Ok, there's 1.  I was under the mistaken myth that temp tables were also stored in memory vs TempDB.  Learn something new every day :).  ----> I'm going to keep reading answers posted but I think I have all the info I need for now.  Thanks to everyone for the great answers!

Comment: A temp table has to be **(1)** created, **(2)** populated, **(3)** used and then **(4)** disposed. A CTE does all this in **one step**

Answer (score 2):

A CTE is generally considered to be more readable than using a temporary table, although that is probably a question of taste. However, more importantly a CTE can be self-referencing and can be even referenced multiple times in the same query. This allows for the development of recursive queries, a very powerful feature when querying hierarchical data structures.

As a word of warning though, there is generally a performance overhead when using CTE, in particular when using multiple CTE's in one query. It is generally faster to use temporary tables with suitable indices, also see @bogdan-bogdanov comment.

Comment: I agree, but they have to be used with caution from my point of veiw - if not properly configured - recursion can cause slow down. I have once such problem. To make code more readable and to avoid subqueries I make CTE, but my code was not very correct and recursion causes slow down.

Answer (score 0):

When think about how a query operates, you should consider subqueries as running before the outer query.  A complex query can therefore be difficult to read and understand as you hop around and mentally consider the result set of each subquery.  It also makes it obtrusive to comment/document the nested subqueries.

When you move a subquery to a CTE, then this is better represented as it becomes a top-down list, instead of nested subqueries.  It makes it easier to see the flow of the query as the top query returns a result which is often then referenced from a later query.  It makes it easier to comment each CTE to describe what its specific purpose is.